# How to put array into labels?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to let the user of my application input data (their school lessons) into six text fields. I believe I have successfully put the data into an array and saved it to `NSUserDefaults`. This is exactly what I have wanted to do so far. **Now it is time to put each individual lesson into a label for Monday through Friday. How can this be done?**

Here is my current code:

```
    -(IBAction)monSave:(id)sender
      {
         NSMutableArray *monLessons;
         monLessons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: self.mon1.text, self.mon2.text, self.mon3.text, self.mon4.text, self.mon5.text, self.mon6.text, nil];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:monLessons forKey:@"MondayLessons"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
      }
```

That was to save the array. Then I did a test using:

```
       [[self.lesson1 monLessons] ObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Note: The data gets saved on a separate view controller than the one which it gets outputted onto.

I am using Xcode 5.

Thank you very much for any help you can offer!

Comment: What is your question? Is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: @Aaron I have updated the OP to bold the question, sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Ok you got your inputs and stored in `NSDefaults`. Now you want to show them back like `<DAY> <LESSON_NAME>` is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to retrieve the values from NSUserDefaults, split the array into several strings, and assign them to different UILabels, right?

You can do:

```
NSArray *lessons = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MondayLessons"];
NSString *s1 = [lessons objectAtIndex:0];
label1.text = s1;

NSString *s2 = [lessons objectAtIndex:1];
label2.text = s2;
```

and so on...

What confuses me is that the variables are named "mon" (monday?) and the array MondayLessons and has six entries... then you want to output them from Monday to Friday?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you. I have now realized that I may have confused you with the Monday through Friday thing but what I meant was that I will use an if statement to check what day it is and if the day is equal to Monday then the Monday array will be displayed. If it is Tuesday, the Tuesday array will appear. Thank you!

Comment: Alright, glad I could help. You're invited to accept the answer :)